# Logic Apps : Use Dynamic content within the Logical functions

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add a condition in Logic apps using one of the field . I have a field named **`score`** .

I want to add a condition and insert to the SQL database column named "Result".

The score returns the values from 1 to 10. I just want to check

- if the value lies between 1-5 means then "Negative"  if the value lies
- between 5-10 means "Positive"

This is what i have done, i have used the logical functions named "if" and wrote the condition as,

```
if(parameters("Score")>5,"Positive","Negative") //just an example to check
```

But it says "The expression is invalid" , how should i correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below. It works for me

```
if(greater(parameters('score'),5) ,'Positive','Negative')
```